# How to fix python request that is not working fully

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to get json data from a url but it's only partially working.

so this works

```
def getData():

    stateList = ["Florida", "Texas","Utah"]

    for state in stateList:
        stateUrl = "https://www.walmart.com/store/finder/electrode/api/stores?singleLineAddr=Texas&distance=25"

        stateDatar = requests.get(stateUrl)
        stateData = stateDatar.json()
        print(stateData)
```

but whenever I put a state variable like this

```
   stateUrl = "https://www.walmart.com/store/finder/electrode/api/stores?singleLineAddr="+state+"&distance=25"
```

so that i can loop through the states, I then begin to get this error

> raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I tried many different things but still don't understand while the looping is producing such error. What is causing the error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please, fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: try adding print(stateUrl) just so you can check what you're feeding into requests

Comment: Actually, this code works for me

Answer (score 1):

You have a list `stateList = ["Florida", "Texas","Utah"]` which I believe you intend to loop through, however, you are looping through `sfile`: `for state in sfile:`.

Comment: sorry that was actually a typo